# Find next row using on condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following table:

Here is the full table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59e05b/5

I need the records to be sorted by event_time and for a specific visitor and then find the time difference between the fields.

I wrote the following query:

```
    SELECT 
A.id, A.visitor_id, A.field_label, A.field_number, A.form_step_num, A.field_type, A.event_time, B.event_time, B.event_time - A.event_time as timediff
FROM form_events A 
INNER JOIN form_events B 
ON B.id = (A.id + 1) 
and A.visitor_id = B.visitor_id 
and A.form_unique_identifier = B.form_unique_identifier ORDER BY A.event_time ASC
```

But the issue is it gives wrong results. How to get the next event time without using B.id = (A.id + 1)?

Here is the right output which I require:

```
id  visitor_id  field_label                 field_number    form_step_num   field_type  event_time          event_time              timediff
1   455         Your Name (required)        5               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:00Z    2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    3
2   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    0
4   455         Your Name (required)        5               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    2018-08-28T08:14:06Z    3
3   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:06Z    2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    4
5   455         Subject                     7               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    0
6   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    3
7   455         Subject                     7               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    0
9   455         Your Message                8               1               textarea    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    0
10  455         Your Message                8               1               textarea    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:15Z    2
8   455         form                        0               1               form        2018-08-28T08:14:15Z                            0
13  458         Your Name (required)        5               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:33Z    2018-08-28T09:34:38Z    5
14  458         Your Name (required)        5               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:38Z    2018-08-28T09:34:40Z    2
15  458         Your Email (required)       6               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:40Z    2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    12
16  458         Subject                     7               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    0
17  458         Your Email (required)       6               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    5
18  458         Your Message                8               0               textarea    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    0
19  458         Subject                     7               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:57Z                            0
```

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: It is MySQL 5.6.

Comment: I have added sqlfiddle so you can try it there

Comment: Sorry due to some reason I can't go to sqlfiddle could you give me the insert script?

Comment: Here is the script - https://shrib.com/#UZkSSJygU2ijW0JhYrKY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `LEAD` function, but it didn't support on `MySQL 5.6`

So You can try to write a subquery to make it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE `form_events` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `visitor_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `page_url` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `form_unique_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `form_step_num` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `field_number` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `form_method` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `form_action` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `form_css_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `form_css_class` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `field_label` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `field_type` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `field_css_id` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `field_name` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `field_css_class` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `event_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `form_events`
--

INSERT INTO `form_events` (`id`, `visitor_id`, `page_url`, `form_unique_identifier`, `form_step_num`, `field_number`, `form_method`, `form_action`, `form_css_id`, `form_css_class`, `field_label`, `field_type`, `field_css_id`, `field_name`, `field_css_class`, `event_name`, `event_time`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 5, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Name (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required', 'click', '2018-08-28 08:14:00', '2018-08-28 08:14:03', '2018-08-28 08:14:03'),
(2, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 6, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Email (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email', 'select', '2018-08-28 08:14:03', '2018-08-28 08:14:06', '2018-08-28 08:14:06'),
(3, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 6, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Email (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email', 'select', '2018-08-28 08:14:06', '2018-08-28 08:14:06', '2018-08-28 08:14:06'),
(4, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 5, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Name (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required', 'change', '2018-08-28 08:14:03', '2018-08-28 08:14:07', '2018-08-28 08:14:07'),
(5, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 7, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Subject\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text', 'click', '2018-08-28 08:14:10', '2018-08-28 08:14:13', '2018-08-28 08:14:13'),
(6, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 6, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Email (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email', 'change', '2018-08-28 08:14:10', '2018-08-28 08:14:13', '2018-08-28 08:14:13'),
(7, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 7, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Subject\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text', 'change', '2018-08-28 08:14:13', '2018-08-28 08:14:17', '2018-08-28 08:14:17'),
(8, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 0, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', 'form', 'form', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form', 'submit', '2018-08-28 08:14:15', '2018-08-28 08:14:17', '2018-08-28 08:14:17'),
(9, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 8, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Message\n      ', 'textarea', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea', 'select', '2018-08-28 08:14:13', '2018-08-28 08:14:17', '2018-08-28 08:14:17'),
(10, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 8, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Message\n      ', 'textarea', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea', 'select', '2018-08-28 08:14:13', '2018-08-28 08:14:17', '2018-08-28 08:14:17'),
(11, 455, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 1, 8, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Message\n    scdcscd  ', 'textarea', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea', 'change', '2018-08-28 08:14:15', '2018-08-28 08:14:17', '2018-08-28 08:14:17'),
(13, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 5, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Name (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required', 'click', '2018-08-28 09:34:33', '2018-08-28 09:34:36', '2018-08-28 09:34:36'),
(14, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 5, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Name (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required', 'change', '2018-08-28 09:34:38', '2018-08-28 09:34:39', '2018-08-28 09:34:39'),
(15, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 6, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Email (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email', 'click', '2018-08-28 09:34:40', '2018-08-28 09:34:43', '2018-08-28 09:34:43'),
(16, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 7, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Subject\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text', 'click', '2018-08-28 09:34:52', '2018-08-28 09:34:55', '2018-08-28 09:34:55'),
(17, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 6, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Email (required)\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email', 'change', '2018-08-28 09:34:52', '2018-08-28 09:34:56', '2018-08-28 09:34:56'),
(18, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 8, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Message\n     ', 'textarea', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea', 'click', '2018-08-28 09:34:57', '2018-08-28 09:34:59', '2018-08-28 09:34:59'),
(19, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 7, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Subject\n     ', 'input', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text', 'change', '2018-08-28 09:34:57', '2018-08-28 09:34:59', '2018-08-28 09:34:59'),
(20, 458, 'http://test.com/', 'FA67841442', 0, 8, 'post', 'http://test.com/#wpcf7-f9-p10-o1', '', 'wpcf7-form', ' Your Message\n     ', 'textarea', '', NULL, 'wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea', 'change', '2018-08-28 09:35:01', '2018-08-28 09:35:03', '2018-08-28 09:35:03');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *, coalesce(event_timeB - A.event_time,0) as timediff
FROM (
    SELECT 
    A.id, 
    A.visitor_id, 
    A.field_label,
    A.field_number,
    A.form_step_num,
    A.field_type,
    A.event_time, 
    (
      SELECT B.event_time 
      FROM form_events B 
      WHERE 
          A.visitor_id = B.visitor_id  
      AND 
          A.form_unique_identifier = B.form_unique_identifier 
      AND
          A.event_time <= B.event_time  
      AND 
          (A.ID < B.ID OR A.event_time < B.event_time )
      ORDER BY B.event_time
      LIMIT 1
    ) event_timeB  
    FROM form_events A
)A
ORDER BY A.event_time ASC
```

**Result**

```
id  visitor_id  field_label                 field_number    form_step_num   field_type  event_time          event_time              timediff
1   455         Your Name (required)        5               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:00Z    2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    3
2   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    0
4   455         Your Name (required)        5               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:03Z    2018-08-28T08:14:06Z    3
3   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:06Z    2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    4
5   455         Subject                     7               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    0
6   455         Your Email (required)       6               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:10Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    3
7   455         Subject                     7               1               input       2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    0
9   455         Your Message                8               1               textarea    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    0
10  455         Your Message                8               1               textarea    2018-08-28T08:14:13Z    2018-08-28T08:14:15Z    2
8   455         form                        0               1               form        2018-08-28T08:14:15Z                            0
13  458         Your Name (required)        5               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:33Z    2018-08-28T09:34:38Z    5
14  458         Your Name (required)        5               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:38Z    2018-08-28T09:34:40Z    2
15  458         Your Email (required)       6               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:40Z    2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    12
16  458         Subject                     7               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    0
17  458         Your Email (required)       6               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:52Z    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    5
18  458         Your Message                8               0               textarea    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    2018-08-28T09:34:57Z    0
19  458         Subject                     7               0               input       2018-08-28T09:34:57Z                            0
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1d1fwUomNUi5LhnFpxoZE/3)

Comment: Thanks for the SQL, but it gives me negative values, which is wrong output. I have updated the right table in my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: The problem is on your `ID` number order. `Id = 4` greater than `3` did you want to base on `id` or`event_time`?

Comment: I want to base it on datetime. Otherwise as you said id 4 has higher datetime than 3 and it would fail that logic.

Comment: Nope, it is giving me wrong output in terms of time. Check the expected output in question.

Comment: Would you consider update the mysql version? there is a simpler way on mysql  8.0

Comment: I'm afraid my host do not support mysql 8.0 yet.

Comment: No problem glad to help

Answer (score 0):

The only issue, this will output 2 columns that you don't need.

```
SELECT 
A.id, A.visitor_id, A.field_label, A.field_number, A.form_step_num, A.field_type, A.event_time,
case when @visitor_id <> visitor_id then @time := event_time end,
@visitor_id := visitor_id,
event_time - @time as timediff
FROM form_events A, (select @visitor_id := 0, @time := 0) t
ORDER BY a.visitor_id, A.event_time ASC
```

Comment: Would this work for MySQL 5.6? When I try on SQLFiddle, it doesn't work.

Comment: I have 5.6 and it works.  I have updated my query for your field name.  I must did a typo somewhere.  What is the error you got?

Comment: On SQLfiddle, it says - Unknown column 'B.event_time' in 'field list'

Comment: Yes, I just removed B.event_time, since there are no more B table.

Comment: The timediff should be in seconds. It gives me output like - 20180828079382

Comment: replace
`event_time - @time as timediff`
by
`TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(event_time, @time))`

Comment: all times are coming as NULL

Comment: As I said, there are 2 "unwanted" columns.  See the last column.  I can see timediff in second, as you wanted.

Comment: Have no idea.  I tried in Mysql Workbench, with mysql 5.6 and it works. But I found an issue with my query.  Here the fixed one :
`SELECT A.id, A.visitor_id, A.field_label, A.field_number, A.form_step_num, A.field_type, A.event_time,
case when @visitor_id <> visitor_id then @time := event_time end eventTime,
@visitor_id := visitor_id visitor_id,
TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(event_time, @time)) as timediff, @time := event_time
FROM form_events A, (select @visitor_id := 0, @time := 0) t
ORDER BY a.visitor_id, A.event_time ASC`

Comment: I tried on my database, it gives values, but incorrect values. Check my question with right values.

Comment: I want the difference of next event - current event for the same visitor_id

Comment: With my technique, I can show the current event, previous event and difference.  But I cannot show next event.  Sorry about that.